# Как подписать и создать APK файл приложения из кода Dart?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, dart, path, apk

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь в Android Studio  подписать и сделать APK файл, из кода на языке Dart. При нажатии кнопки подписать и сделать APK файл у меня выходит ошибка в таком виде "Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android API 30 platform (C:/Users/Sergey/AppData/local/Android/Sdk).
Я так понимаю что тут что-то связано с переменной среды, но я могу ошибаться.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Какая версия Android Studio?

Comment: 2 недели назад скачал, самая новая

Comment: А версия JDK какая? На сколько я знаю нужна JDK 1.8.

Comment: Указано  8.0.3210.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Если какой-то способ поможет, опишите его как ответ на ваш вопрос на русском языке